# How to position top in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, material-swift

I try to add a material swift card to the top of my view, but it always is shown too high. To set the height of the card fixes the problem but i don't want to set the height.

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Here is a link to an image which shows how the card looks like normaly: 
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f22d27c712a6fba12237a3e4b11f6e10c893d9ab/687474703a2f2f7777772e636f736d69636d696e642e636f6d2f676966732f77686974652f636172642e676966

And here is the code of my view:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class UserProfileView: UIView {


    fileprivate var card: Card!

    fileprivate var toolbar: Toolbar!
    fileprivate var moreButton: IconButton!

    fileprivate var contentView: UILabel!

    fileprivate var bottomBar: Bar!
    fileprivate var dateFormatter: DateFormatter!
    fileprivate var dateLabel: UILabel!
    fileprivate var favoriteButton: IconButton!

    convenience init(){
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.24, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0)

        prepareDateFormatter()
        prepareDateLabel()
        prepareFavoriteButton()
        prepareMoreButton()
        prepareToolbar()
        prepareContentView()
        prepareBottomBar()
        prepareImageCard()
        prepareMainView()
    }


    fileprivate func prepareMainView() {
        self.addSubview(self.card!)

        let views = [
            "card": self.card!
        ]
        self.card?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let cardHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[card]-10-|", metrics: nil, views: views)
        let cardVerticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[card]", metrics: nil, views: views)

        self.addConstraints(cardHorizontalConstraint)
        self.addConstraints(cardVerticalConstraint)
    }

}

extension UserProfileView {
    fileprivate func prepareDateFormatter() {
        dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    }

    fileprivate func prepareDateLabel() {
        dateLabel = UILabel()
        dateLabel.font = RobotoFont.regular(with: 12)
        dateLabel.textColor = Color.blueGrey.base
        dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date.distantFuture)
    }

    fileprivate func prepareFavoriteButton() {
        favoriteButton = IconButton(image: Icon.favorite, tintColor: Color.red.base)
    }

    fileprivate func prepareMoreButton() {
        moreButton = IconButton(image: Icon.cm.moreVertical, tintColor: Color.blueGrey.base)
    }

    fileprivate func prepareToolbar() {
        toolbar = Toolbar(rightViews: [moreButton])

        toolbar.title = "Material"
        toolbar.titleLabel.textAlignment = .left

        toolbar.detail = "Build Beautiful Software"
        toolbar.detailLabel.textAlignment = .left
        toolbar.detailLabel.textColor = Color.blueGrey.base
    }

    fileprivate func prepareContentView() {
        contentView = UILabel()
        contentView.numberOfLines = 0
        contentView.text = "Material is an animation and graphics framework that is used to create beautiful applications."
        contentView.font = RobotoFont.regular(with: 14)
    }

    fileprivate func prepareBottomBar() {
        let clipboardButton = IconButton(image: UIImage(named: "clipboard_darken1.png"))
        let dashboardButton = IconButton(image: UIImage(named: "dashboard_darken1.png"))
        let bookmarkButton = IconButton(image: UIImage(named: "bookmark_darken1.png"))
        let dotsButton = IconButton(image: UIImage(named: "dots_darken1.png"))

        bottomBar = Bar()
        bottomBar.centerViews = [clipboardButton, dashboardButton, bookmarkButton, dotsButton]
    }

    fileprivate func prepareImageCard() {
        card = Card()

        card.toolbar = toolbar
        card.toolbarEdgeInsetsPreset = .square3
        card.toolbarEdgeInsets.bottom = 0
        card.toolbarEdgeInsets.right = 8

        card.contentView = contentView
        card.contentViewEdgeInsetsPreset = .wideRectangle3

        card.bottomBar = bottomBar
        card.bottomBarEdgeInsetsPreset = .wideRectangle2
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the controller where the view is loaded:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView(){
        self.view = UserProfileView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what's the Problem?

Comment: You are not adding anything to the screen in your code. Where are you adding this to the screen and positioning it?

Comment: The first line of `prepareMainView()`

Comment: Please don't post full screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that status bar is 20 points high and view controller's view is pinned to the screen top. Your `card` 10 points below superview's top, so it ends up under status bar (10 points below status bar's bottom edge).

The solution is to use `UIViewController`'s `topLayoutGuide`:

```
override func loadView() {
    // this will create default blank view and set it to the 'view' property
    super.loadView()

    let userProfileView = UserProfileView()
    view.addSubview(userProfileView)

    // pin userProfileView left and right edge to superview's left and right edges 
    // its top to view controller's topLayoutGuide
    // and its bottom to view controller's bottomLayoutGuide
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting this:

```
views["topLayoutGuide"] = topLayoutGuide
let cardVerticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[topLayoutGuide]-10-[card]", metrics: nil, views: views)
```

Another option is to replace this

```
fileprivate func prepareMainView() {
    self.addSubview(self.card!)

    let views = [
        "card": self.card!
    ]
    self.card?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cardHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[card]-10-|", metrics: nil, views: views)
    let cardVerticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[card]", metrics: nil, views: views)

    self.addConstraints(cardHorizontalConstraint)
    self.addConstraints(cardVerticalConstraint)
}
```

with

```
fileprivate func prepareMainView() {
    view.layout(card!).horizontally(left: 10, right: 10).top(10)
}
```

That's it :)

**Edit**

Update to [Material 2.4.3](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.4.3) to have this work perfectly.

Comment: i changed my code, but it still behave the same way